# Inserting structs in sorted linked list and writing it to binary file

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, linked-list, binaryfiles

I have one serious problem. I need to write a program in which I input person details like first name, last name and age to a struct, which also contains pointer to the next person and than I need to write that to binary file. It must be ascending sorted by last name and than by first name, like linked list, using pointers, but only one pointer pointing to next struct. After entering all data it needs to go through file and find the struct with the lowest value and than using pointers print all data in ascending order. 
This is the code I wrote but it's not working. I need help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct person{
    char firstName[20], lastName[20];
    int age;
    person *next;
};



 void insert(char filename[], int n){
    person *head = NULL;

    ofstream people(filename, ios::binary | ios::trunc);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        system("cls");
        person *per = new person;
        cout << "firstName: ";
        cin >> (*per).firstName;
        cout << "lastName: ";
        cin >> (*per).lastName;
        cout << "age: ";
        cin >> (*per).age;


        if(head == NULL) {
            (*per).next = head;
            head = per;
            }
        else{
            person *curr = head;
            person *prev = NULL;
            bool end = false ;
            while(!end){
                if(strcmp((*curr).lastName, (*per).lastName) ||
                   (!strcmp((*curr).lastName, (*per).lastName) && 
                   strcmp((*curr).firstName, (*per).firstName))){
                    end = true;
                    }
                else {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = (*curr).next;
                }
            }

            if(curr==head){
                (*per).next= head;
                head = per;
             }
             else{
                (*per).next = curr;
                (*prev).next = per;
             }
        }

        people.write((char *)&(*per), sizeof(*per));
    }

    people.close();
}

    void print(char filename[])  {
     person *head = NULL;
     person *el;
     person c,min;

     ifstream people(filename, ios::binary);

     people.read((char *)&c, sizeof(c));
     min = c; 
     while(!people.eof()){
        people.read((char *)&c, sizeof(c));
        if(strcmp(c.lastName,min.lastName)== -1 || 
        (!strcmp(c.lastName,min.lastName) && 
        strcmp(c.firstName,min.firstName)==-1)){
            min = c; 
         }   
        }
        head = &min;
     while (head != NULL) {
      cout << (*head).firstName << " " <<(*head).lastName <<" "<< 
      (*head).age << endl;
      el = head;
      head = (*head).next;
      delete el;
    }people.close();
 }


 int main() {

    int n, a;
    char filename[40];

    cout << "filename: " << endl;
    cin.getline(filename, 40);
    do{
        do{ system("cls");
            cout << "Choose one of the options: "<<endl;
            cout << "1. insert "<<endl;
            cout << "2. print "<<endl;
            cout << "0. exit "<<endl;
            cin >> a;
        } while(a<1||a>2);
            switch(a){
                case 1: cout << "How many people would you like to enter? ";
                        cin >> n;
                        insert(filename, n); 
                        break;
                case 2:print(filename);
            }


    } while(a!=0);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What undesired behavior are you observing? "Why is my code not working?" is not a suitable question for Stack Overflow without the necessary supporting information.

Comment: So, if I have more than two people, the moment I enter data for second person it chrashes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are trying to create a sorted list but your condition for place to insert new node is wrong

```
strcmp((*curr).lastName, (*per).lastName) ||
               (!strcmp((*curr).lastName, (*per).lastName) && 
               strcmp((*curr).firstName, (*per).firstName)
```

It essentially tells - insert new person before curr as soon as it is different from curr.
You have to change it to be - insert new person as soon as it is bigger than (less than) curr - depending on the order of sorting.

So instead of checking strcmp != 0 check strcmp >0 or <0

Of course replacing c-strings with std::string will make it a lot easier and safer

Comment: It didn't fix the problem, but thank you for the answer.